# Is solution without starvation also solution without deadlocks? And vice versa?

Tags: deadlock

I was just wondering...

Is solution without starvation also solution without deadlocks? And vice versa,
is solution without deadlocks also solution without starvation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution without starvation would mean the system is "fair"; each thread has just enough access to a shared, limited resources to make progress. In this case I would assume there are no deadlocks. Deadlock is the end of the road for starving threads... they all starve and no one makes progress.

A solution with no deadlocks could still have cases where only a subset of the threads have "fair" access to a shared, limited resource. The remainder of threads would starve.

Comment: Thank you for your response.


And what about aging?
Is solution with aging also solution with deadlock, and is solution without deadlock also solution without aging?

Comment: Aging is a technique to prevent starvation by incrementally increasing the priority of a thread the longer it waits. If it waits long enough eventually it will have the highest priority and gain access to the limited resource it desires.

Comment: Alright, got it. Thank you for your time. I would give you thumb up, but I don't have enough reputation.  :)

Comment: And just to confirm, so If we do not have deadlock, does that mean we also do not have aging?

Comment: I don't think so. If you don't have deadlock, you could still have thread aging and ultimately starvation.

Comment: If I got this correct: Aging technique = NO starvation. And NO Starvation = NO deadlocks. 
But if we DO have deadlocks, it does NOT mean we have Aging or Starvation?

Comment: Since a deadlock causes all threads to starve, and using aging would prevent starvation I think your first observation is theoretically sound. The second should be, "If we DO have deadlocks, we have starvation". When thinking about this focus on the relationship between deadlocks and starvation. All deadlocks lead to _everyone_ starving. _Someone_ starving does not always lead to deadlock. Aging is slightly tangential as it is a technique to prevent starvation.